# database how to log queries (Postgres and Oracle Express)?

Tags: postgresql, logging, oracle10g

There are 3 applications that uses two databases, I want to log ANY query that is sent by them.
My db's are `Oracle 10g` and `Postgres 8.4`, how can it be done?

Comment: Why are you using outdated and unsupported versions for both systems? For Postgres see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's an old system that i need to debug.

Comment: This is two questions with two answers. For PostgreSQL, did you search for "postgresql log queries" or "postgresql log all queries"? It's well covered by the documentation and there are plenty of existing SO and DBA questions. I'll probably close this as a duplicate and let you post a new one for Oracle if a quick Google search doesn't find you the answer.

Comment: Dup of http://serverfault.com/q/20106/102814

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger, but WHERE should i set this line? i'm not a dba and new to pg\oracle (also, i agree, i will delete it myself)

Comment: `postgresql.conf`. See [runtime configuration and logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) The PostgreSQL manual is fairly approachable, so I strongly recommend having a read of the tutorial and server admin sections. It'll be handy.